# What is solo programming?

Tags: methodology

I was searching on information about solo programming approach and I couldn't find any details.

What does solo programming mean?

What are the benefits and weaknesses of solo programming?

When should we use it?

What are the software metrics we should use when measuring solo programming?

Is solo programming traditional models?

I really need information in detail.

Answer (score 5):

Solo Programming is almost invariably used to contrast against Pair Programming (XP, Agile)

There is a lot of info around on "what":

[pair programming and solo developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412799/pair-programming-and-solo-developer)

http://isr.journal.informs.org/cgi/content/abstract/19/1/71

IMHO there is a trade off - Solo has increased productivity, but at the cost of lower Quality

Comment: Talking about productivity without quality is like living in the communist era. In those times (in Romania at least), people were always talking about how productive the country was, and how great the leader was. Unfortunately, the quality was almost always very low. So... increased productivity with lower quality is no productivity at all.